# Python - Match word but not word with another word next to it

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace values in /etc/nslcd.conf file with values in a parameters file.  There are two parameters that are causing me so much heartache.

```
base dc=example,dc=com
base   group ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

The parameters file has values for these two variables like this

```
base = dc=company,dc=org
base   group = ou=admingroups,dc=company,dc=org
```

I'm cycling through each parameter after storing them in a dictionary like this

```
for key in sorted(d):
  item = key
  print("Processing Key:", item)
  with open ('/etc/nslcd.conf', 'r') as fr:
    with open ('/tmp/nslcd_tmp', 'w+') as fw:
      # Iterate through lines in nslcd.conf file
      for line in fr:
        # Some options are commented and some are not
        itemy = '#' + item
        if line.startswith(item) or line.startswith(itemy):
          print('Replaced value for:', item)
          fw.write(item + '' + d[item])
        elif item == 'base   group':
          fw.write(item + '' + d[item])
        else:
          fw.write(line)
```

The problem I'm having...
1. Since there are keys such as uri that are mentioned multiple times in the file, I have to cycle through all the lines and replace all of them.
2. So, first 'base' goes through and replaces all lines beginning with 'base' with 'base dc=company,dc=org' and there is no more 'base   group' item to replace.

How can I tell it not to match 'base' in 'base   group'?  These are not the only items I'm replacing and so I to keep it generic as much as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following your problem here. Can you show a more complete, clear input example of both files, a clear description of the transformation you're trying to perform, your expected output result and the result you're actually getting? Thanks.

Comment: I want the script not to modify the lines with 'base   group'  thinking its lines containing 'base'.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with getting the configuration key from the configuration line and find if it matches a configuration that needs to be overridden instead of having multiple loops level. The following code uses a regex to extract the configuration key with a capturing group selector.

```
import re

regex = '^#?\s*(\w+\s*\w*)\s\w*='

d = {
    "base": "dc=company,dc=org",
    "base   group": "ou=admingroups,dc=company,dc=org"
}

with open ('nslcd.conf', 'r') as fr:
    with open ('result.conf', 'w+') as fw:
        for line in fr:

            line = line.strip()
            match = re.search(regex, line)

            if match and match.group(1) and match.group(1) in d:
                key = match.group(1)
                fw.write(('', '# ')[line.startswith('#')] + key + ' ' + d[key] + '\n')
            else:
                fw.write(line)
```